# SurfaceView with custom thread takes long to appear on screen

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview

I used [this tutorial](http://https417.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/threading-surfaceview-in-android.html) to create a SurfaceView for a game. The tutorial fixed the problems I had with handling the thread but now whenever I open the fragment it takes anywhere between 3 and 15 seconds for the screen to turn yellow.

I thought it might have something to with the code in the container activity but the only thing I changed is this fragment alone. The speed before the change was fine.

```
public class VirtualMapFragment extends Fragment {

private MapSurfaceView mapSurfaceView;

@Override
public void onResume() {
    if (mapSurfaceView != null){
        mapSurfaceView.surfaceRestart();
    }
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(mapSurfaceView == null)
        mapSurfaceView = new MapSurfaceView(getActivity());

    return mapSurfaceView;
}


@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (mapSurfaceView != null){
        mapSurfaceView.surfaceDestroyed(mapSurfaceView.getHolder());
    }
    super.onPause();
}

private class MapSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private SurfaceThread surfaceThread;

    public MapSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        surfaceThread = new SurfaceThread(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        surfaceThread.restartSurface();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        surfaceThread.terminateSurface();
    }

    public void surfaceRestart(){
        if (surfaceThread != null){
            surfaceThread.restartSurface(); 
        }
    }
    public void doDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawColor(Color.YELLOW);

    }

    @Override 
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        return false;
    }


}

private class SurfaceThread implements Runnable {
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private MapSurfaceView mMapSurfaceView;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    volatile Thread thread;

    public SurfaceThread(MapSurfaceView mapSurfaceView){
        mSurfaceHolder = mapSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mMapSurfaceView = mapSurfaceView;
        mCanvas = new Canvas();

        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void terminateSurface(){
        this.thread.interrupt();
    }

    public void restartSurface() {
        if (thread.getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED){
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();  // Start a new thread
        } 
    }

    public SurfaceHolder getSurfaceHolder() {
        return mSurfaceHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                mCanvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                if (mCanvas == null){
                    mSurfaceHolder = mMapSurfaceView.getHolder();
                } else {
                    synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                        mapSurfaceView.doDraw(mCanvas);
                    }
                }   
            } finally {
                if (mCanvas != null) {
                    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(mCanvas);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What are the various threads doing during that period?  i.e. is run() blocked on the `synchronized` call?  Attach a debugger and pause the app while it's "stuck".  See also https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity

Comment: The problem was that the thread was put to TimedWait (do not know why). Solved the problem by not dealing with a thread directly but rather using a Handler. It worked like a charm and there is absolutely no delay now.